# How to free space from ubuntu dev/sda1 to install another OS

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, disk

[Current disk structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByImc.png)
only have dev/sd1 with full disk space how can I resize it to get some unallocated space for installing another os?

Answer (score 1):

You can not resize partition in use, so since you boot from it - you need another bootable media.

- Make backup of important documents/files, resize operation may fail
  and you'll loose everything
- Charge to 100% if you have battery
- Make a bootable USB with Ubuntu. [One of possible ways](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0)
- Boot from it, choose **try without installing** in boot menu
- Run gparted and change size of existing partition, decide how much
  you need for new os. This operation takes time, and must not be
  canceled/braked
- Install new OS, then boot into Ubuntu and run `update-grub`. New os
  will appear in grub menu after that

  If you have booting problems, boot USB Ubuntu, install and run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Click "Recommended Repair"